# Replace whole line in vim

Tags: vim

So I have the following text snippet in my file. I am using vim to edit it.

```
Internal Problem Description
----------------------------
!!! Please enter the internal description of the problem.
```

So to fill up the problem description I go to the line that starts with !!! and then first do a `dd` and then press `I` to go to insert mode. Then I start typing text for the problem description.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Something like replacing an entire line in vim with a single command.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296473/how-can-i-quickly-delete-a-line-in-vim-starting-at-the-cursor-position is helpful: pressing 'C' will delete the rest of the line and go to insert mode

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Jump to the line that starts with the bangs with something like:

   ```
   /!!<CR>
   ```
2. Enter insert mode with:

   ```
   S
   ```

   or

   ```
   cc
   ```

See `:help S`.

Comment: What is `<CR>`?

Comment: The enter key. See `:help key-notation`.

Answer (score 4):

The `S` command will do that. But you should also look into a *snippet solution*, which allows multiple placeholders and automatic jumping to them.

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

Comment: what does `S` stand for? Also what do you mean by ":abbreviate on steroids". Can you please give me some context?

Comment: It's a command name, probably a mnemonic for `S`ubstitute. You apparently use snippet files which you `:read` into the buffer, but for small text fragments like yours, defining `:abb`reviations directly in Vim would work, too. Snippets are even more powerful, as I've described.